# first() vs. where('id', '=', 1)->first()

Tags: laravel, eloquent, multi-tenant

Is there any **difference** between these three:

```
someModel::where('id', 1)->first();
```

```
someModel::where('id', '=', 1)->first();
```

```
someModel::first()
```

what about these two?

```
someModel::skip(1)->take(4)->get();
```

```
someModel::where('id', '!=', 1)->take(4)->get();
```

.

I'm adding **multitenancy** to an existing product (**single DB approach**). I was wondering if I could simply **replace all**

```
where('id', 1)->first();
```

statements with

```
 first();
```

?

Comment: As a side note to the answers below, don't rely on or assume that `Mode::first()` will return a record with `id` of `1`. If the record with `id` of `1` has been deleted, you'll get a record with the first lowest `id`. However, that assumes my second point that you can change the default order records are returned from the database to be `descending` rather than `ascending`. So `Model::first()` would return the highest `id` record in such cases. Better to be explicit about the `id` you want.

Comment: Its dangerous to assume that the record you want has id of 1 unless you have something else that is storing the fact that you need record with key of 1.  Using first() just says give me the first record you find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. These are same:

   ```php
   Model::where('id', 1)->first();
   Model::where('id', '=', 1)->first();
   ```

   But this may give you result if model with id 1 was deleted:

   ```php
   Model::first();
   ```
2. These are different:

   ```php
   Model::skip(1)->take(4)->get();
   Model::where('id', '!=', 1)->take(4)->get();
   ```

   In the first case, you will skip any model regardless of its ID. In the second case, you are excluding only model with ID 1.
3. No you can't, that's different queries. But you can replace

   ```php
   Model::where('id', 1)->first();
   ```

   with

   ```php
   Model::find(1);
   ```

Answer (score 3):

when you omit the operator, laravel will translate it as EQUAL

so these 3 have the same queries,

```
someModel::where('id', 1)->first();
//equals to
SELECT * FROM `somemodels` WHERE `id` = 1 LIMIT 1

someModel::where('id', '=', 1)->first();
//equals to
SELECT * FROM `somemodels` WHERE `id` = 1 LIMIT 1

someModel::find(1);
//equals to
SELECT * FROM `somemodels` WHERE `somemodels`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
```

while these last one has different query

```
someModel::first()
//equals to
SELECT * FROM `somemodels` LIMIT 1
```

and these are the queries of your additional question

```
someModel::skip(1)->take(4)->get();
//equals to
SELECT * FROM `somemodels` LIMIT 4 OFFSET 1

someModel::where('id', '!=', 1)->take(4)->get();
//equals to
SELECT * FROM `somemodels` WHERE `id` != 1 LIMIT 4
```